# Relative difference in numpy.testing.assert_allclose

Tags: python, numpy

I could not understand how `numpy.testing.assert_allclose` method is calculating relative difference between two arrays. Is it calculating in percentage or without taking percentage? For example, If I have two arrays

```
import numpy as np 

gfg1 = [1, 2, 3] 
gfg2 = np.array([4, 8, 9])
np.testing.assert_allclose(gfg1, gfg2)
```

the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py", line 1515, in assert_allclose
    verbose=verbose, header=header, equal_nan=equal_nan)
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py", line 841, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0

Mismatch: 100%
Max absolute difference: 6
Max relative difference: 0.75
```

Max absolute difference is understood but what about relative difference?

Comment: I guess it is max( (4 - 1) /  4, (8 - 2) / 8, (9 - 3) / 9) = 0.75?

Comment: FYI: It looks like the most explicit statement about this is in the Notes section of the docstring for [`numpy.allclose`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [source code of `assert_allclose`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ee49178517088966e63c2aedf6a8a5779ad5384/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L1473) you will see that it calls [`assert_array_compare`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ee49178517088966e63c2aedf6a8a5779ad5384/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L697). And inside the `assert_array_compare` you can see that the maximum relative difference is calculated as [`max(error[nonzero] / abs(y[nonzero]))`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ee49178517088966e63c2aedf6a8a5779ad5384/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L828) where the `error` is [`abs(x - y)`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ee49178517088966e63c2aedf6a8a5779ad5384/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L812).

So, in your case, for `x = np.array([1, 2, 3])` and `y = np.array([4, 8, 9])`, you get

```
max_rel_error == max(|1-4|/|4|, |2-8|/|8|, |3-9|/|9|) == 0.75
```